# " g++ not installed " even after installing it " sudo apt-get install g++ "

Tags: g++

i recently installed Ubuntu on a VMware and following a tutorial... 
gcc works for me, but when i try g++, it says " The program 'g++' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install g++ " but, when i do and return to compile a c++ file. It still says the same thing.

**EDIT**

1. I tried reinstalling it, didn't work. It doesn't give any error messages per say, but it opens a list of packages that are "the newest version" and when i search for g++ among them, it isn't there.
2. I tried to locate where it exists, with command " ls -l /usr/bin g++ " i get, " no such file or directory. "
3. output of command " lsb_release -a " 
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
   Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
   Relase: 14.04
   Codename: trusty.
4. output of command "uname -a"
   Linus ubuntu 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 20 15 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
5. I get nothing by typing " command -v g++ ".
6. And I dont see g++'s description like the others i see when i use "apt-cache policy g++".

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a; command -v g++; apt-cache policy g++`

Comment: I didnt get what u mean as i'm totally new to linux and programming @A.B.

Comment: **How** did you try to reinstall it? If you used `apt-get`, you should add the `--reinstall` flag explicitly i.e. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++` rather than just `sudo apt-get install g++`

Comment: I just remembered something, if its the reason i'll be damned!. I don't have access to internet in my VMware Ubuntu. Is this the reason?

Comment: Give me the exact output of `apt-cache policy g++` and output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: You have no internet access? Configure your virtual machine to use  network bridge and DHCP.

Answer (score 4):

What solved this problem for me was simply uninstalling then reinstalling in 2 steps:

```
sudo apt-get remove g++  
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: I need g++ 8, but this installs g++ 7

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem after installing CUDA. It turns out g++ was there but was a broken symbolic link. You can check if this is your case by doing:

```
ls /usr/bin | grep g++
```

and if it exists, its probably a broken link, so just do `sudo rm /usr/bin/g++` and then create a new symlink:

```
sudo ln -s g++-7 /usr/bin/g++
```

(This assumes g++-7 exists, or some other version of it)

Comment: 2023 update : `sudo ln -s g++-11 /usr/bin/g++`

Answer (score 1):

You have done the right thing to install `g++`, so we need to investigate why it still isn't working.  Here are some things to try:

1. Try installing it again: `sudo apt-get install g++`.  You should get the message `g++ is already the newest version`.  If not, what message do you get?  Do you get any error messages?
2. Find out what is where `g++` should live.  Type `ls -l /usr/bin/g++`.  You should find a simlink to the actual binary:

   ```
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  7  2014 /usr/bin/g++ -> g++-4.8
   ```

   Sometimes things can go wrong here if `/usr/bin/g++` points to somewhere in `/etc/alternatives`, but the `/etc/alternatives` link points to the wrong place.
3. Ask back here.  When you ask back here, including the output of commands such as `lsb_release -a`, `uname -a`, `command -v g++`, and  `apt-cache policy g++` would be very helpful, as recommended by @A.B.  In fact, if you ask back here, it's best to do so by editing your question above rather than by asking a new question.

Answer (score -1):

If you already have multiple versions of g++ they will be called with the version number on the end. See the output of:

`ls /usr/bin/g++*`

I have:

`/usr/bin/g++-5  /usr/bin/g++-7`

Instead of calling `g++` I need to call `g++-5` or `g++-7`

Comment: Using `ls -l /usr/bin/g++*` you might notice [the need of a symlink](https://askubuntu.com/a/874723/349837), for example `/usr/bin/g++ -> g++-5`.

Comment: `/usr/bin/g++` is a file in the `g++` package, so it should be there. Having multiple versions doesn't remove the file.