# Setting up symlink for g++?

Tags: symbolic-link, g++

Currently, this is setup such that g++ points to g++-5.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           5 Feb 11  2016 g++ -> g++-5
```

However, if I were to do ln -s /usr/bin/g++-5 /usr/bin/g++, I would then get

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           5 Feb 11  2016 g++ -> /usr/bin/g++-5
```

after running `ls -l /usr/bin`.

Is there a way I can get the /usr/bin/ part not to show up when I run ls -l?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create it as a *relative link* using the  form

```
ln -s g++-5 /usr/bin/g++
```

From `man ln`:

> Symbolic links  can  hold
>          arbitrary  text;  if  later resolved, a relative link is interpreted in
>          relation to its parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just go into the directory where your binaries are located and create your symlink from there:

```
cd /usr/bin/
ln -s g++-5 g++
```